# Given sum of two numbers A and B find maximum product of A and B

Tags: math, product, maximize

Given sum of A and B let S 
i have to find maximum product of A*B 
but there is one condition value of A will be in range [P,Q]

How to proceed for it ?

If there is no range then task is pretty simple.

Using derivation method .

How to find Maximum product for eg.

A+B=99
value of A will be range [10,20]

then what will be the maximum product of A and B.

O(N) will not sufficient for the problem

Comment: You should actually try something before resorting to StackOverflow. Please show your efforts by adding some code, some reasonings, or narrowing the scope of the question. In its current form, it looks like you asking someone else to do your homework...

Comment: Hint: this is a closed problem. Meaning: you can _elaborate a formula_ which will give you the maximum in O(1).

Comment: The product is maximum when the two values are equal(to Sum/2), so the maximum product would be (value of A in [P,Q] closest to Sum/2)*(corresponding B). Edit: In your example, maximum product would be 44*45(if A and B can take any values) but with the given constraint, it would be 20*79

Comment: It may be closed problem but not easy to find the problem on stackoverflow i tried did not find anything then i post it , please elaborate the approach .

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Homework is your training. You should try hard to solve it by yourself before searching SO or anywhere else on the Internet.

Comment: ok :) will do it and thanks to you also @tewathia

Comment: O(N) is meaningless here, as there is no N parameter ! If one states that A must be an integer, then an exhaustive search will be O(Q - P). But if A is not constrained, exhaustive search makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, `B = S - A` and you need to maximize `A * (S - A)`.

You know from algebra that `A * (S - A)` achieves a maximum when `A = S / 2`.

If `S / 2` falls in the allowed range `[P Q]`, then the maximum value is `A^2 / 4`.

Otherwise, by monotonicity the maximum value is reached at one of the bounds and is the largest of `P * (S - P)` and `Q * (S - Q)`.

This is an O(1) solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a maths question, nothing to do with programming

Even if you are given it as a programming question, You should first understand it mathematically.

You can think of it geometrically as "if the perimeter of my rectangle is fixed at S, how can I achieve the maximum area?"

The answer is by making sides of equal length, and turning it into a square. If you're constrained, you have to get as close to a square as possible.

You can use calculus to show it formally:

```
A+B = S, so B = S-A

AB therefore = A(S-A)

A is allowed to vary, so write it as x

y = x(S-x) = -x^2 + Sx

This is a quadratic, its graph Will look like an upsidedown parabola

You want the maximum, so you're looking for the top of the parabola

dy/dx = 0

-2x + S = 0

x = S/2
```

A better way of looking at it would be to start with our rectangle Pq = A, and say P is the longer edge.

So now make it more oblique, by making the longer edge P slightly longer and the shorter edge q slightly shorter, both by the same amount, so P+q does not change, and we can show that the area goes down:

```
Pq = A

(P+delta) * (q-delta) 
    = Pq + (q-P)*delta + delta^2  
    = A + (q-P)delta
```

and I throw away the delta^2 as it vanishes as delta shrinks to 0

```
    = A + (something negative)*delta
    = A - something positive
```

i.e. < A

Comment: thanks @Pi and your example is quite easy to understand